# pre-creating sockets without knowing whether they are IPv4 or IPv6

Tags: ios, c, sockets, ipv6, ipv4

I have some code which works by pre-creating sockets (via. socket() BSD API), and then at a later time when the address is known it will do the connect() etc. This works with IPv4 but now I am refactoring to support IPv6 as well.

The problem is that it seems that when I do the initial socket() I need to put in AF_INET or AF_INET6. However since I don't know the address yet I don't know which is correct. Is there anyway to create a generic socket which will work for either? If I use AF_INET6 and I am on a IPv4 network, am I correct in assuming it will not work?

A related question - Even though I don't know the IP address yet, is it possible I can detect what network my device is on: IPv4 or IPv6? Assuming one network interface, I think I can only be one of those networks, so if I can find a way to detect what type of network my device is on, then I can do that at socket creation time.

Another option is to refactor to create the socket only when I know the address, but there is a big codebase and I would like to avoid that if possible.

I'm writing code that runs on iOS, but I am not sure if that is relevant here.

Comment: Some platforms support *dual-stack* sockets (sadly, iOS is not one of them, especially with Apple pushing iOS to support only IPv6 exclusively). Where available, you can create an `AF_INET6` socket for IPv6 and then disable the `IPV6_V6ONLY` option on it to allow IPv4 via [IPv4-mapped IPv6 addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6#IPv4-mapped_IPv6_addresses).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want to do is not possible. When socket is created, it is associated with stack protocol, and IPV6 and IPV4 are just different stack protocols.

However, the real question is **why** do you precreate sockets? Why not create the socket when you need to?

And last, but not the least, your assumption is incorrect. Your device can have multiple interfaces - one for IPv4, another for IPv6 - and use them both.

Comment: @SanderSteffann, yeah, i am curious too.

Comment: It might be a good answer (I **didn't** down-vote), but I'm not sure that it covers everything... what about using the `AF_UNSPEC` socket family, allowing the protocol binding to wait for the `bind`... I know this refers to listening sockets (I can listen to both IPv4 & IPv6), but it might be relevant to explain how this applies (or doesn't apply) to a client socket.

Comment: @Myst, AF_UNSPEC is not a standard valid option for domain. As far as I know only Windows supports it, and OP is using OS X.

Comment: @SergeyA, `AF_UNSPEC` works on my Mac (BSD), it's specified on the [Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getaddrinfo) and I believe (didn't check) it complies with POSIX.1-2001. I picked it up from [Beej's guide](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/ipstructsdata.html#structs).

Comment: @Myst, what you are saying is not relevant to the question in any way. You are talking about getaddrinfo parameter. As `getaddrinfo` parameter AF_UNSPEC is, of course, valid and allows you to pick an interface which matches both families. But it doesn't mean you can create a socket using AF_UNSPEC as a domain! (effectively what OP would like to do).

Comment: @SergeyA, as I pointed out, I don't think the answer is wrong, I just think that it would be more complete if it pointed out the information about `getaddrinfo` and `AF_UNSPEC` to answer the OP's question: "is it possible I can detect what network my device is on: IPv4 or IPv6?"

Comment: @Myst, OP assumes the device can only have one interface (IPv4 or IPv6). This assumption is not correct, and I mentioned it in my question. OP didn't ask how to get all available interfaces for device, so I didn't answer this (unasked) question.